# T-SQL processing speed slow down after loading 25 million records

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql, configuration

The question is why am I having a slow down at 25 million records. Is this a SQL Server config issue, code or both?

After approximately 25 million records loaded, in the routine `pGetOHLCBetweenTwoDates(...)` (see code below) the following line

```
SqlDataReader rdr = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader();
```

takes 20 times as long to load records from via T-SQL (SQL Server). It does not matter how many records are loaded per pass (50k, 100k,250k) it is always at around 25m records that the slow down occurs (see logs excerpts below).

It is not a resource issue, the system this is running on has 128 gb memory, dual 8 cores and SQL Server has 8 gig of memory avail, SQL Server is running locally, SQL Server was increased to 32 gig to see if that would fix the issue, it did not. I see the same thing on the SQL server profiler side 500-600 ms jumping to 10,000 - 30,000 ms.

> idxLoadPos 25249999 - Elapsed time 00:00:00.9609748
>   idxLoadPos 25099999 - Elapsed time 00:00:00.5936540
>   idxLoadPos 24949999 - Elapsed time 00:00:00.5890105
>   idxLoadPos 24799999 - Elapsed time 00:00:11.5260435  <---<< Approx 25 million records loaded
>   idxLoadPos 24649999 - Elapsed time 00:00:10.9329704
>   idxLoadPos 24499999 - Elapsed time 00:00:11.2460554

Code:

```
public static int GetOHLCBetweenTwoDates(ref OHLCArray ohlcArray, int currentIndex, DateTime fromDate, DateTime toDate, DataFeedConfig dataFeedConfig)
{
    // loads an array bottom up to match the standards in TA-LIBRARY in C Sharp
    DateTime fDate = fromDate;
    DateTime tDate = toDate;
    int recordCount = SQL.GetCountBetweenTwoDates(fromDate, toDate, ohlcArray.TimePeriod, dataFeedConfig);
    int maxReturnCount = LoadRecordCount;
    //int maxReturnCount = 100000;
    int getRecordCount = maxReturnCount;
    int remainingRecordCount = recordCount;
    int idxArrayLoadPosition = currentIndex;

    Console.WriteLine("SQL - int - GetOHLCBetweenTwoDates from: {0}, to: {1}, getRecordCount: {2} ", fDate.ToString(), tDate.ToString(), getRecordCount.ToString());

    while (fDate <= tDate & remainingRecordCount > 1) //0
    {
        getRecordCount = (remainingRecordCount < maxReturnCount) ? remainingRecordCount : maxReturnCount;
        fDate = SQL.pGetOHLCBetweenTwoDates(ref ohlcArray, ref idxArrayLoadPosition, getRecordCount, fDate, tDate, ohlcArray.TimePeriod, dataFeedConfig);
        remainingRecordCount -= (getRecordCount - 1); // no -1
        Console.WriteLine("SQL - GetOHLCBetweenTwoDates from: {0}, to: {1}, getRecordCount: {2} ", fDate.ToString(), tDate.ToString(), getRecordCount.ToString());
    }

    idxArrayLoadPosition++;

    if (idxArrayLoadPosition == -1) { idxArrayLoadPosition = 0; }

    return idxArrayLoadPosition;
}

private static DateTime pGetOHLCBetweenTwoDates(ref OHLCArray ohlcArray, ref int idxArrayLoadPosition, int recordCount, DateTime fromDate, DateTime toDate, Enums.TimePeriodTypes tpt, DataFeedConfig dataFeedConfig)
    {
        DateTime returnDate = new DateTime(1901, 01, 01);

        string database = "" + dataFeedConfig.Exchange + "." + dataFeedConfig.Issue + ".Data"; //string database = "[" + Exchange + "." + Issue + ".Data]";
        string userName = dataFeedConfig.sqlLoginCredentials.SQLUserName;
        string password = dataFeedConfig.sqlLoginCredentials.SQLPassword;
        string server = dataFeedConfig.sqlLoginCredentials.SQLServerName;
        string tableName = "Data." + tpt;

        string connString = "server=" + server + ";uid=" + userName + ";pwd=" + password + ";database=" + database + ";Integrated Security=True;";
        string databaseAndTable = "[" + database + "].[dbo].[" + tableName + "]"; /* [database].[dbo].[table], database = [Exchange.Issue.Data], table = [Data.TimePeriods(enum)] */
        string sqlQueryString = "SELECT  TOP " + recordCount.ToString() + " * FROM " + databaseAndTable + " WHERE  [dtTime] >= '" + fromDate.ToString() + "' AND [dtTime] <= '" + toDate.ToString() + "' ORDER BY [dtTime] ASC";

        using (SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connString))
        {
            sqlConnection.Open();
            using (SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand(sqlQueryString, sqlConnection))
            {
                SqlDataReader rdr = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader();
                while (rdr.Read())
                {
                    ohlcArray.dtTime[idxArrayLoadPosition] = (DateTime)(rdr.GetSqlDateTime(0));
                    ohlcArray.High[idxArrayLoadPosition] = (double)(rdr.GetSqlDouble(1));
                    ohlcArray.Low[idxArrayLoadPosition] = (double)(rdr.GetSqlDouble(2));
                    ohlcArray.Open[idxArrayLoadPosition] = (double)(rdr.GetSqlDouble(3));
                    ohlcArray.Close[idxArrayLoadPosition] = (double)(rdr.GetSqlDouble(4));
                    ohlcArray.Volume[idxArrayLoadPosition] = int.Parse(rdr.GetSqlInt32(5).ToString());

                    returnDate = ohlcArray.dtTime[idxArrayLoadPosition];
                    idxArrayLoadPosition--;
                }
                rdr.Close();
            }
            sqlConnection.Close();
        }
        return returnDate;
    }
```

Any ideas on which direction to go next to solve this?

Edit: more info ... the tables have this structure:

```
string cTable = "CREATE TABLE " + dbAndTable + " ([dtTime] [datetime] NOT NULL,[Bid] [float] NULL, [Ask] [float] NULL,[Volume] [float] NULL) ON [PRIMARY] ";

string cIndex = "CREATE INDEX " + indexName + " ON " + dbAndTable + " (dtTime)";<br/>
```

Should the `[dTime]` column be a primary key as opposed to just an index?

Comment: " t-sql has 8 gig of memory avai", T-SQL is a language. It doesn't have "available memory" nor any other similar concept used here. Did you mean SQL Server has 8GB of memory available?

Comment: `SqlDataReader` is also disposable.

Comment: May I ask why you are loading millions of records into memory?

Comment: @Camilo - SQL server has 8 gig of memory available.

Comment: @Crowcoder - thanks. I would have thought that being in a using statement it would be closed. Testing that now.

Comment: @CodingYoshi - 200 million records actually. Evolutionary algorithms on large scale data sets take forever if you are reading them over and over from a from a drive.

Comment: @Crowcoder - closed SqlDataReader and the issue still exists.

Comment: Are you running a 32 or 64 bit application? Increasing memory on a 32 bit application may not fix the issue as the process will have limited access to memory and this may be triggering GC to collect what is not referenced or to promote items up in generations. Have you run a memory profile on the application?

Comment: Also have you attempted to run this in SSMS and see if you experience the same issue? Also are you using SQL Server or SQL Server Express / LocalDB?

Comment: Are the records being added already ordered by `dtTime`? It may be helpful to read up on how to [Reorganize and Rebuild Indexes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/reorganize-and-rebuild-indexes). The article also contains information on checking index fragmentation.

Comment: I didn't expect that to fix it, but it wouldn't hurt.

Comment: You are loading 20 million records into memory and assert it is not a resource issue?  Object memory can fragment.  Why are you getting as GetSql then casting.   There is  GetInt and GetDouble.  This is messed up.

Comment: @Toni Kostelac it is a 64 bit application with <gcAllowVeryLargeObjects enabled="true" /> set in the app config. The array that the data is loaded into is created then all elements are initialized. It is not a resource issue in that respect.

Comment: @Toni Kostelac I am using SQL Developer 2014

Comment: @HABO All the records being added are added in dtTime order. The database was dropped and the table was just reloaded before I posted the question here.

Comment: @paparazzo up to 200 million records as an array and initialized (every variable set to a default) it just slows down around the 25 million mark, and memory wise it is not a resource issue (3-5 gig out of 128 gig), it is probably an issue with unreleased resources either server or client or both. The type casting is removed by the compiler and I find it easier to read, like adding "this.fieldName" as opposed to "fieldName" to classes.

Comment: If you wish to solve this I'd say you'd need to do something like a memory / cpu profiling to see what's going on at the 25M record mark. Without having the stored procedure, the data and the application running there is no help anyone can give you.

Comment: Also, having programmed some AI a few years back that read data from a database I never experienced the bottle neck to be the database, rather the CPU for all the number crunching.

Comment: @Crowcoder thanks, you solved it.  No idea why this works ...  using (SqlDataReader rdr = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader()) { while (rdr.Read()) { ... code goes here ...  } rdr.Close(); }  .... without the rdr.Close() at 25 million records, the time it takes increases 50-60 fold (500 ms to ~30,000 ms)

Comment: Well, Dispose suppresses GC Finalization where Close() doesn't but I had no idea that would make enough difference.

Comment: @ToniKostelac _"I never experienced the bottle neck to be the database, rather the CPU for all the number crunching"_ That is a totally valid point when you are working with a single model. When you have a half a million models, that need to be processed on a nightly basis, the drive speed is the issue. Load the data once and process in memory in lot 1,000.

Comment: @Crowcoder Thanks again, the load times are substantially reduced. No idea why, they just are and you pointed me in the direction that worked.

Answer (score 1):

My friend your biggest problem is the implicit data conversion you are forcing sql server to do for you by converting from the strings  "fromdate" and "todate" to the datetime datatype you established with your provided CREATE TABLE statement.

This is punishing processing running on such a large table. I believe you should

1. Modify the CREATE TABLE statement to include a primary key with a clustered index on an identity(1,1) column for your table.
2. Modify the CREATE INDEX using the INCLUDED option for the columns Bid,Ask and Volume.
3. Write a stored procedure passing as parameters your desired TOP, LOWER DATE FLOOR AND UPPER DATE CEILING AS datatypes INT, DATETIME, DATETIME.
4. Refactor your calling code to execute the stored procedure.

These are all well established best practices as I understand them.

Followup: I noticed that you are implementing paging after bringing all records back from the db ... instead implementing paging with SQL SERVER using FETCH NEXT will speed processing. Implement the necessary parameters on the stored procedure.

Answer (score 0):

First thing we need to know the delay type:

Please run sp_whoisactive @get_plans=1. Google and download whoisactive if you didn't have one.

Then check the wait type column. It would tell you the wait types. Please post here we can take a look.

Without knowing the wait types, there are a few possible reasons: 
1.
Usually after loading 25m rows, your buffer pool would be affected: existing cached data or compiled plans might be pushed out back to make room for loaded rows.

2. You might have async_network_io wait type, it does not necessarily mean you have network delay one of possible reason was that SQL SERVER is waiting for the client to process the data before sending more data.

Comment: There is no way for me to post the output here it is ~8000 char too long.